# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. XV

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You and the hiker walk through passageway

> T

and are surprised to find yourselves in a forest clearing.

There seems to only be one path, but there is also a piece of paper nailed to a tree:

`980 970 470 011 101 950 930 730 630 490 630 140 040 830 140 040 140 040 240 611 670 711 990 501 201 070 501 860 230 380 611 101 170 230 480 501 230 101 280 960 401 911 230 511 501 230 380 501 401 480 850 430 830 830 630 460 490 730 460 260 330 101 090 560 770 230 121 901 230 970 480 011 370 230 280 560 070 230 380 501 270 611 230 611 370 230 301 011 370 701 560 901 230 011 111 230 380 870 111 370 480 790 801 711 611 560 411 170 011 111 990  There is a drawback, but you can change it...`

You want to find out what it says before continuing through the forest... Ready, set, go!

---

**Current Points:**
Joshua Bizley -- <strike>24</strike> <strike>19</strike> 14 points

Shoover -- <strike>15</strike> <strike>40</strike> 109 points

Omega Krypton -- <strike>40</strike> <strike>60</strike> 67 points

Jan Ivan -- 100 points

SEE PART XI FOR INFORMATION ON HOW POINTS WORK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:

> you revert each number (or just whole text) and transform to ASCII:
>  `conGrAtulaTIoNS on mAkIng It tHiS FAR InTO my MAZe!>@%^@$&&":ThiS is whERe iT GetS DiFficuLt*()()&()$^$%';enJOY`

Some ideas

> Only uppercase: GATINSAIIHFARITOMAZTSERTGSDFLJOY
>  But I believe it is a dead end.
>  It looks like some console/programming language, because of `>`,`:`  and `;` on "correct" places - almost like [this one](https://tio.run/#ecndpcaalrlp) - it also [reverse text](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P9fIS4lpyg/XEEnPycn1UPDQfP/fwA) and so…

But that is all I have, maybe it will help someone.

Comment: That's literally the whole answer... +100 points to you!

Comment: I think this was another one I made too easy... But congratulations, all the same!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath ok then. You can try more layers like this puzzle. Also with hints in story or so.